# Make specific view fullscreen

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I have an activity that contains many dynamically created `LinearLayout`s of different posts.  The heirarchy is `ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> post LinearLayout`.  In these post `LinearLayout`s there are `ImageView`s.  How do I make an `ImageView` fullscreen when it is clicked?

I tried using `ImageView.setOnClickListener()` and implementing it as:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

But this fullscreens the `Activity`, not the specific `ImageView`.

So I tried to create an `Activity` that is fullscreen and displays this `ImageView`, but this requires the image to be `Serializable` so that it can be passed into the `Intent` as an extra.

How do I do this?

Comment: why are u passing image in intent.just pass its id or complete path.

Comment: Please provide the code you have done in tht activity..so can modify that as you required..

Answer (score 0):

try this,
create an xml file

`<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
            android:src="@drawable/app_back1"/>
  </LinearLayout>`

inflate above xml file in popupwindow.

`public void onClick(View view) {
          PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext()); 
          popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
         final View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fullimage,null);
          popupWindow.setContentView(v);
          if (!popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                ImageView image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
                image.setImageDrawable(view.getBackground());
          }
}`

Answer (score -1):

Set LayoutParams as FILL_PARENT in both width and height

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
 //getSupportActionBar().hide();if you need hidden actionbar also
  view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
 }
```